# How i can establish connection between KEPWARE and Influxdb

Tags: influxdb, plc, opc-ua, telegraf

I am working on the automation of data collection, storage, and analysis. The project consists of three main steps: first, connecting Kepware to the PLC to collect data; second, connecting Kepware to InfluxDB for data storage; and finally, connecting InfluxDB to Grafana to configure the dashboard. I have successfully completed the first step, but I am currently struggling with the second step. After conducting several research, I found that using Telegraf could potentially solve the issue. However, I am unable to successfully relate it to Kepware. Any ideas or suggestions on how to proceed with this step?

I've tried to connect kepware to influxdb with telegraf and opc ua protocol